# Is there any way to generate JS source maps in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, source-maps

Versions:

- Ruby: 2.3.4
- Rails: 4.2.9
- sprockets: 3.6.3
- sprockets-rails: 2.3.3

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/glebtv/compass-rails-source-maps

Comment: @NickM this can be used with compass and i am not using it.